# Replace the column names in all the files based on the lookup values in Python

Tags: python

I have a requirement where I need to standardize all the column names from all the files under a root directory and subdirectory

suppose my root directory is *C:\Test\Project_files* and under this folder I have 3 more subdirectories
Project 1,Project 2,Project 3. Each subdirectory has one csv file in it.

The Files are named in a required format, for ex: 100_abc.csv. 200_def.csv etc

[100_abc.csv file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiNXL.png)

I have a lookup file from which i need to replace the column names of 100_abc.csv file based on the project_id field

[Lookup File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiNXL.png)

The project id field should be taken from the filename (100_abc.csv), In this case 100 (anything before the first occurence of _ (underscore)) is the project id (it can be alphanumeric as well), based on this project id it has to match the headers from 100_abc.csv file with the src_val from the lookup file and replace them with the Tgt_val in all the files

Please help me out guys, am very new to Python and tried so many ways but I am not able to proceed further after loading the data to the dataframe

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: I dont have any clue on how to code, as of now I have only this 
import pandas as pd;
import os;
import glob;
import numpy as np;
import csv;
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Test\\Lookup.csv");

print(df);

path = r'C:\Test\Project_files'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

print(all_files)